# Storm Ack method

Tags: real-time, apache-storm

Currently I have a simple topology.  It has a spout to read data in, a bolt to transform the data and a bolt to store the data in a data store.  I have setup anchors in order to get reply on any tuples that fail.  Due to the way I read data in, there is only one spout but multiple transformer and store bolts.  Now, what I have noticed is when the number of tuples in the cluster gets large the topology runs very slow.  When I removed the acking everything went much faster.  So I tried to increase the number of ackers but I noticed that there was still only one acker thread tracker all the tuples.  Is it always just one acker thread per spout to track the tuples?